# if command to change innerHTML

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've used a lot of `getElementById.innerHTML` to populate a table on click of certain buttons. I want to have a function where it will use an if command, so that, when clicked, if the text in box id 'B2' is 'x' then it will return 'y' in id 'pc2', if not (else) , it will return 'z' in element with ID 'pc2'. I can't get it to work.

Here's what I tried, please help.

```
if (document.getElementById("B2").innerHTML = 'x' { 
    document.getElementById("pc2").innerHTML = 'y'
} else {
   document.getElementById('pc2').innerHTML = 'z'}
}
```

I have tried it by putting each step into variables and no difference. It changes what is in B2 and treats it as `true` regardless.  Thanks very much, I'm very early to all this and don't know jQuery, just rudimental java.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `==` except of `=` in condition statement.

```
if (document.getElementById('B2').innerHTML == 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double equal operator `==` inside the `if`.

```
if (document.getElementById("B2").innerHTML=='x')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not check for equality but you assign a new value to the element with ID 'B2'. Try the following:

```
if (document.getElementById('B2').innerHTML == 'x') {
    document.getElementById('pc2').innerHTML = 'y';
} else {
    document.getElementById('pc2').innerHTML = 'z';
}
```

Comment: Thanks folks but this doesn't seem to work for me. B2 is a blank table cell that gets populated by getElementById.innerHTML from another button. I'm asking it to effectively read the text in B2 and if it says 'x' to write into another box.

Comment: Please share your html code with us, because of what I understand right now the various answers here all do what you describe but maybe there is a misunderstanding ...